# Node.js - assign writable stream to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, streaming

As in below code, I can write base64 encoded stream into a file but I want to assign the base64 encoded string to a variable rather than creating a file so that I can use it for the purpose I want. How can I assign `response.pipe(base64.encode());` to a variable as base64 encoded string ? I am using `base64-stream` to encode incoming stream.

```
const request = xero.call('GET', `/Invoices/${invoiceId}`);
  request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/pdf');

  request.on('response', async (response) => {
    const data = response.pipe(base64.encode());
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(`${invoiceId}.txt`);
    data.pipe(file);
  });
  request.end();
```

Answer (score -1):

To store the contents of the stream as a string you need to concatenate the base64 stream and then store that buffer as a variable.  For that I like to use `concat-stream`.

keep the stream around with `const data = response.pipe(base64.encode());`

but then

```
data.pipe(concat(buf => {
  const str = buf.toString('base64')
})
```